# local variable access in 'method local inner classes'

Tags: java, methods, inner-classes, final

What is the internal reason due to which within **method local inner class** we can only access final or effectively final local variables of the method in which that inner class is declared? 
Please see below example.

```
class Test{
    int i = 10;
    static int j = 20;
    public void m1(){
        int k = 30;
        //k=40;
        final int m = 40;
        class Inner{
            public void m2(){
                System.out.println("value of i = " + i + " value of j = " + j + " value of k = " + k + " value of m = " + m);
            }
        }
        Inner i = new Inner();
        i.m2();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test t = new Test();
        t.m1();
    }
}
```

If I try to change the value of variable `k` (line commented in source code), then there will be compiler error stating "local variables referenced from an inner class must be `final` or `effectively final`"
Also in java versions lower than 1.8, local variables must be explicitly defined as final if you want to access that variable within method local inner class.

Comment: check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class?rq=1), it covers this point too.

Comment: @curiosa Thanks for the link. 

`The gain is that a local inner class instance is tied to and can access the final local variables of its containing method. When the instance uses a final local of its containing method, the variable retains the value it held at the time of the instance's creation, even if the variable has gone out of scope`

I believe this is what related to my question from the link you have shared. Could you please share some sample code so I can understand this use-case? Thanks much

Comment: can someone respond please??

Comment: You can take a look at the explanation in the [Java 8 tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html).

Comment: Or, probably even better [here](http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-method-local-inner-classes.php#scope-and-use-of-local-inner-classes)